# Is there a Java command that means "if any button is pressed"?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to work on some code I did for a dice rolling app, where if the roll button was pressed it would display random dice sides.
I am trying to re-use this concept for my multiple choice quiz app, where if any button is pressed, right, or wrong, it will move on to the next question:

I was thinking it would look something like this, with "button" representing all buttons being pressed.
However in this multiple choice quiz there will only be 4 buttons (A, B, C and D) that I want to have cause this happen if pressed. I'm sure I could make this happen by repeating the paragraph of code 4 times with each button, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way to have all 4 buttons be represented on the same line

(A lot of the code I'm showing is meant to be for a dice app it's mainly the first word of the first line I want help with)

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("multic", "the Button has been pressed!");

                Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

                int number = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(8);

                Log.d("Dicee", "the random number is: " + number);

                leftDice.setImageResource(diceArray[number]);

                int number1 = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(8);

                rightDice.setImageResource(diceArray[number1]);


            }
        });
```

I expect that after one of the buttons is pressed it will move on to the next question.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the listener like this:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("multic", "the Button has been pressed!");
        Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
        int number = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(8);
        Log.d("Dicee", "the random number is: " + number);
        leftDice.setImageResource(diceArray[number]);
        int number1 = randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(8);
        rightDice.setImageResource(diceArray[number1]);                
    }
};
```

and then set it to as many buttons as you want:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
button3.setOnClickListener(listener);
button4.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single listener object with a switch statement to check which button is clicked.

```
Button b1,b2;
//findViews
View.OnClickListener listener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //code
        switch((Button)v){
            case b1:
                //code
                break;
            case b2:
                //code
                break;

        }
        //code
    }
};
b1.setOnClickListener(listener);
b2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a multiple choice quiz, with a set of 4 possible answers, I would suggest that you use a `RadioGroup` with constituent `RadioButtom` objects, like so:

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pirates"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ninjas"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Notice how each `RadioButton` has the `onClick` attribute. You can name the same method for all radio buttons, and then in the activity or fragment use one method for all buttons with a switch statement, like so:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

To read more: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton#java

Comment: Thank you so much :), i'll check that out.

Comment: Do you think it matters if I put the radio buttons in a constraint layout?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Can I have more specifics?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple different choices as i am thinking it:

1)
Set `android:onClick="onNextQuestion"` on xml of all your buttons.
then in your java code write:

```
public void onNextQuestion(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button click
}
```

2) (Better as can work in [more cases](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#ClickListener)) Make an `NextQuestionClickListener` class which will implement the interface  `View.OnClickListener` and will implement the method `onClick` doing the code you wish.

```
class NextQuestionClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something in response to button click
        }
}
```

Then set the listener to each button:

```
NextQuestionClickListener nextQuestionClickListener = new NextQuestionClickListener();
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
...
button1.setOnClickListener(nextQuestionClickListener);
button2.setOnClickListener(nextQuestionClickListener);
...
```

3) Using RxJava and [RxBindings](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding)

```
RxView.clicks(button1)
.mergeWith(RxView.clicks(button2))
.mergeWith(RxView.clicks(button3))
.mergeWith(RxView.clicks(button4))
.subscribe(aVoid -> {
    // Do something in response to button click
}, throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "error in handling click of next question", throwable));
```

4) Also i found [butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) where you can do:

```
@Onclick({R.id.button1,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,R.id.button4})
void onButtonClick(View aView) {
    // Do something in response to button click
}
```